# Improper Quotations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wasn't going to ask this questions as it seemed too "easy" to figure out but I'm still unable to come to a solution for this.

I have my query in quotations and it's causing errors:

```sql
-- Original 
'"'+ lnv.Name +'"' As [Column Name]
```

```sql
-- Trying to put the Original into OPENQUERY.
''"''+ lnv.Name +''"'' As [Column Name]
```

How do I properly put the original into proper quotations within an OPENQUERY?

Thanks.

Comment: Can  you post the whole `OPENQUERY` segment please?

Comment: `OPENQUERY` executes the query on the destination server.  Your second example with `' ' " ' '` is the correct syntax for openquery, but if the destination database is not SQL Server, it may not allow using `+` for string concatenation which is probably your actual issue.  What's the error message you're getting and what type of database is the destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL SERVER` requires double `'` marks. So applying that rule:

```
OPENQUERY(<something>, ''"''+ lnv.Name +''"'' As [Column Name]')
```